# Unable to store each word from text file in doubly linked list in c++

Tags: c++, file, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I want to read from text file which contains following data :

"This is a small file containing words ."

I want to store it's each word in each node like.

node1 : This , node2 : is, node3 : a, node4 : small ... etc

Now, upon running below code it is just storing the last character " **.** " two times.

Can anyone suggest what mistake I am doing here.

I am a noob so just from basics.

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    string num;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct node *create_ll(struct node *start)
{
    string word;

    ifstream file;

    file.open("/Volumes/MAC Extended/Softwares/Xcode/DSA project/DSA project/file.txt",
              ios::in);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "File Does not Exist";
        return 0;
    }
    struct node *new_node, *ptr;
    while (file >> word)
    {
        if (start == NULL)
        {
            new_node = new node;
            new_node->prev = NULL;
            new_node->num = word;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            start = new_node;
        }
        else
        {

            ptr = start;
            new_node = new node;
            new_node->num = word;
            while (ptr->next != NULL)
                ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new_node;
            new_node->prev = ptr;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: It wont hurt you however in `struct node *next;` you don't need the struct on this line in `c++`.

Comment: In C++ consider writing a LinkedList class and using a constructor rather than `create_ll` and free-floating nodes.

Comment: Why are you reimplementing the wheel and writing your own `std::list`? Also, why not use a `std::vector`? It performs better almost always.

Comment: Well whole correction will be appreciated. But that doesn't affect anything according to me @drescherjm

Comment: @JesperJuhl it is clear that it is learning exercise.

Comment: Why are you allocating two new nodes in your `else` branch? I can't follow your logic here.

Comment: @user4581301 There is no `LinkedList` class in C++, sorry.

Comment: Just remove the line `start = new_node;` and the two lines before the `while (ptr->next != NULL)` loop. You allocate double nodes

Comment: @SergeyA Poor wording on my part. I am suggesting the asker write a linked list class.

Comment: yeah sorry for that typo error @SergeyA

Comment: @SergeyA No, that's *not* clear. The question does not say so and I've seen too many people try to reimplement the standard library *not* as a learning exercise that I'm not going to rule out stupidity by default.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, fine, you might be right. I still believe it is a learning exercise, but it is probably not really *clear*.

Comment: Please check the new edit. A whole code snippet will be much helpful

Comment: This edited version should work :-), your problem was what @A._A and SergeyA pointed out.

Comment: Yeah thanks @SergeyA for pointing out

Comment: Suggestion: rather than iterating the list every time to add an item to the end, store a pointer to end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user4581301 but I follow the rule "If a code works, then never touch it" . No offence though

Comment: That is perfectly reasonable thinking. Always have a good reason to make a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  DSA project
//
//  Created by Vivank Sharma on 26/03/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Vivank Sharma. All rights reserved.
//

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    string num;
    struct node *prev;
};
struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *create_ll(struct node *);
struct node *display(struct node *);
int main()
{
    int option;

    do
    {
        cout<<"\n\n *****MAIN MENU *****";
        cout<<"\n 1: Create a list";
        cout<<"\n 2: Display the list";
        cout<<"\n\n Enter your option : ";
        cin>>option;
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
            { start = create_ll(start);
                cout<<"\n DOUBLY LINKED LIST CREATED";

            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                start = display(start);
            }
                break;
        }
    }while(option!=3);
}
struct node *create_ll(struct node *start)
{
    string word;

    ifstream file;

    file.open("/Volumes/MAC Extended/Softwares/Xcode/DSA project/DSA project/file.txt",ios::in);
    if (!file) {
        cout << "File Does not Exist";
        return 0;
    }
    struct node *new_node, *ptr;
    while(file>>word)
    {
        if(start == NULL)
        {
            new_node = new node;
            new_node -> prev = NULL;
            new_node -> num = word;
            new_node -> next = NULL;
            start = new_node;
        }
        else {

            ptr=start;
            new_node = new node;
            new_node->num=word;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL)
                ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new_node;
            new_node->prev=ptr;
            new_node->next=NULL;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
struct node *display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr -> num<<endl;
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

This will do. Found the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
struct node *next;
string num;
struct node *prev;
};
struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *create_ll(struct node *);
struct node *display(struct node *);
int main()
{
int option;

do
{
    cout<<"\n\n *****MAIN MENU *****";
    cout<<"\n 1: Create a list";
    cout<<"\n 2: Display the list";
    cout<<"\n\n Enter your option : ";
    cin>>option;
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
        { start = create_ll(start);
            cout<<"\n DOUBLY LINKED LIST CREATED";

        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            start = display(start);
        }
            break;
    }
}while(option!=3);
}
struct node *create_ll(struct node *start)
{
string word;

ifstream file;

file.open("/Volumes/MAC Extended/Softwares/Xcode/DSA project/DSA 
project/file.txt",ios::in);
if (!file) {
    cout << "File Does not Exist";
    return 0;
}
struct node *new_node, *ptr;
while(file>>word)
{
    if(start == NULL)
    {
        new_node = new node;
        new_node -> prev = NULL;
        new_node -> num = word;
        new_node -> next = NULL;
        start = new_node;
    }
    else {

        ptr=start;
        new_node = new node;
        new_node->num=word;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = new_node;
        new_node->prev=ptr;
        new_node->next=NULL;
    }
}
return start;
}
struct node *display(struct node *start)
{
struct node *ptr;
ptr=start;
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    cout<<ptr -> num<<endl;
    ptr = ptr -> next;
}
return start;
}
```

> try this code

Comment: This is a code-only answer. They are frowned upon because they tend to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). This answer can be salvaged by pointing out what you changed, why you changed it, and how it solves the asker's problem.